# Including Config file in connection file not working

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a CMS that provides dynamic database creation at the initial project setup stage.

I have defined the database configuration details as constants in config.php file:

```
//Database Name
define('DEFAULT_DB_NAME', 'cms');

//User Name
define('DEFAULT_USER_NAME', 'root');

//Password
define('DEFAULT_PASSWORD', '');

//Host Name
define('DEFAULT_HOST_NAME', 'localhost');
```

I included the config.php file in my database connection file (db.class.php):

```
<?php
include_once '../../config/config.php';

class Db{
    protected $conn;
    protected $host = DEFAULT_HOST_NAME;
    protected $username = DEFAULT_USER_NAME;
    protected $password = DEFAULT_PASSWORD;
    protected $dbname = DEFAULT_DB_NAME;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        if($this->conn->connect_error){
            die("<h3>Connection Failed!!! Error: " . $this->conn->connect_error . "</h3>");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have created a dynamic Style sheet (admintheme.php) that modifies the admin panel based on user preference:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css;");

    include_once '../../model/admintheme.class.php';

    $theme = new Admintheme();
    $result = $theme->ReadAdminTheme();

    if($result == '' || $result == '0'){
        $sidebarBg = "#111";
        $sidebarPosition = "left";
        $sidebarunset = "left";
        $sidebarright = "unset";
    }
    else{
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
        $sidebarBg = $row['sidebarbg'];
        $sidebarPosition = $row['sidebar_position'];

        if($sidebarPosition == "left"){
            $sidebarunset = "right";
        }
        else{
            $sidebarunset = "left";
        }
    }
?>
/*-- ------------------------xx----------------------- */

/***** Content Section Starts *****/
.content{
    margin-<?= $sidebarPosition; ?>: auto;
}
/***** Content Section Ends *****/


/**** Side Bar Section Starts *****/
.sidebar-nav{
    background-color: <?= $sidebarBg; ?>;
    <?= $sidebarPosition; ?>: 0px;
}
```

The issue is that when I use static data in "db.class.php" file (ex. directly write "localhost" in place of the constant and so on..) then "admintheme.php" works fine and displays the desired output, but when I use constants in place of the static data then all other functionalities of the project work fine and retrieve data from the database except "admintheme.php".

The "admintheme.php" also works fine when the constants are defined inside the "db.class.php" or if the "config.php" file is in the same directory as of the "db.class.php" but while including the the "config.php" file from other directory, all other data is retrieved except "admintheme.php".

**No direct error is received but in the browser's console, it states (include_once(../../config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...)

**Included path is correct in both "db.class.php" and "admintheme.php".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your paths are wrong. You are adjusting the include path based on the current php environment setup (which could be different from machine to machine, and also location of initial php you hit in an url). You really should use `__DIR__` as the base, and navigate from the file that is doing the including. This way it pulls from where you know you have put it in relation to the file doing the pulling.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks for your response and I will surely consider using __DIR__ in the project. But I use VSCODE as the text editor and it displays suggestions of files while including them also I have manually cross verified the path but I didn't found any issues.

Comment: Well you have an issue clearly ;) because "*No such file or directory*" ... meaning its not finding the file at the path traversal that is occurring.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Adding '__DIR__'  solved the issue.....thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "**DIR**" magic constant solved the issue.